# How can I run controller action with whenever gem in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

for example I have a controller "Posts" and action "create". Can I run it from terminal?

I want to use `whenever` gem:

```
every 2.hours do
    # I want to run posts#index
end
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to call your controller action from cron? Wouldn't be better if you only run what should be done, for example rake task that creates `Post`?

Comment: I want to run it every 2 hours. How can I do it then? @MarekLipka

Comment: I know you want to run it every 2 hours. The question was *why* do you want to call it every 2 hours?
Write your rake task that would make request to proper address (with `Net::HTTP` for example) and it should work.

Comment: Like @MarekLipka said,  while your app is running, locally or in a remote server, you can use any http client like [rest_client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to post data to your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is create a class that execute the `create` logic:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    creator = PostCreator.new(params)
    creator.process
  end
end
```

So you can use this class in the `Whataver`'s job:

```
every 2.hours do
  creator = PostCreator.new({ whatever: 'you want'})
  creator.process
end
```

Comment: This is a reasonable solution.